# How to have a customized CSS style for a bootstrap component?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I have the code below that has a bootstrap offcanvas at the left. I wondered how I can change the width of the collapsed sidebar. Bootstrap does not have a style tag to do that. I searched and I saw some people suggested using a customized CSS style to define new styling. Can you please help me with that I am pretty new to styling, and I don’t know where I should start.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash_iconify import DashIconify

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SPACELAB])

sidebar = dbc.Nav([
            dbc.NavLink([
                html.Div(page["name"], className="ms-2"),
            ],  href=page["path"],
                active="exact",
            )

for page in dash.page_registry.values()

],  vertical=True,
    pills=True,
    className="bg-light",
)

download_icon = DashIconify(icon='ic:baseline-menu', width=40, style={})

app.layout = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Row([

        dbc.Col(
            html.Div("Drilling Dashboard",
                style={'fontSize': 40,
                       'textAlign': 'center',
                       'color': 'white'}
            )
        ),

        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Button([download_icon, ''], id="open-offcanvas", n_clicks=0),
        ],  width=1,
            style={'margin-right': 0,
                   'padding': 5}
        ),
    ]),

    html.Hr(
        style={'margin-top': 0}
    ),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Offcanvas(
            dbc.Col([sidebar], width=5), id="offcanvas", title="Title", is_open=False, style={'horizontal-width': 10}
        ),
    ]),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([dash.page_container], xs=8, sm=8, md=10, lg=10, xl=10, xxl=10)
    ])
], fluid=True,
    style={'background-color': 'black'})


@app.callback(
    Output("offcanvas", "is_open"),
    Input("open-offcanvas", "n_clicks"),
    [State("offcanvas", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_offcanvas(n1, is_open):
    if n1:
        return not is_open
    return is_open

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: select the component using its class name or id and apply the CSS property from your side. Also, sometimes you might want to add !important at the end of each property which must be overwritten. Make sure you link your CSS file after you call BootStrap.

Comment: @YUVI_1303 Thanks for your reply. Is that possible to show me an example of a webpage to look for? I am quite confused about how to do that.  In the css file can I only write the styling for the collapsed canvas pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the width of sidebar by the following attribute:

```
dbc.Offcanvas(
            dbc.Col([sidebar], width=8),
            id="offcanvas", 
           title="Title", 
           is_open=False, 
           style={'width': 100}  #<---- this attribute instead of horizental-width
        )
```

**Output**

[image]